# Flutter : Could not find package "build_runner"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I work with [Hive Packages](https://docs.hivedb.dev/custom-objects/generate_adapter), I implement Modularization in my project.
first i create packages with name `network` with run command `flutter create --template=package network`, I reference [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages).

This packages include models of my project. after that I create model user, then run command build the model `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'user_model_hive.g.dart';

@HiveType()
class UserModelHive extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0) 
  DateTime id;
  @HiveField(1)
  String giverName;
  @HiveField(2)
  String pinCodeNumber;

  UserModelHive({this.id, this.giverName, this.pinCodeNumber});
}
```

But I get error like this

> `Could not find package "build_runner". Did you forget to add a dependency? pub finished with exit code 65`

I'm sure already include `build_runner` in my packages `network`.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: network
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^1.1.1
  hive_flutter: ^0.2.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^0.5.2
  build_runner: ^1.7.2

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # To add assets to your package, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  #
  # For details regarding assets in packages, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  #
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # To add custom fonts to your package, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts in packages, see
  # https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I'm already use this command but nothing happens:
`flutter packages get` & `flutter pub get`

It's my structure folder if you needed.
[image: my structure folder]

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: Yes , already solved this issue in here https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2581

Answer (score 28):

I also got the same error. I have resolved it by adding `build_runner` in `dev_depndencies`, in `pubspec.yaml` file like:

```
dev_dependencies:
    build_runner: ^2.4.6
    mobx_codegen: ^0.3.9
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try the code below:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the GitHub issue posted shared in the comments, the issue was caused by running the app from a different directory. In this case, the app was being run on root in the issue posted. The issue has been solved by running the app from `/network`.

Answer (score 3):

Run this commands in your terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing these things

1. Adding build_runner in dev dependencies
2. Converting @HiveType(0) to @HiveType(typeId: 0)

After this run these comman

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to install latest version to dev dependencies:

```
dart pub add build_runner --dev
```

Ps: needed in case you use json parsing plugin ([json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable))

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by running the following:

1. `dart pub add build_runner --dev`
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced to this issue

I change my model class @HiveType() annotation

```
@HiveType(0)
```

Like that.Problem solved.

(I was posting here for future developers who faced to this)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I ran `flutter pub run build-runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`.

The issue is that I've been writing `build-runner` and not `build_runner`

Comment: Could not find package `build_runner` or file `build_runner`

Comment: @LucaZiegler have you declared it in your pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem now, even after adding under dev_dependencies/ dependencies and still it isn't working.

(For Vs code)Then just type 'CTRL+P' and select 'add dependencies' and type 'build_runner', try adding from here.

It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

I add build_runner into dev dependency and run this command :

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```